Increment of regularly varying function tends to infinity
Consider a function $f(x)$ that is regularly varying when $x\rightarrow\infty$ and with index greater than 1. This means for some $\gamma > 1$ and any $\lambda > 0$,  $f$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)} = \lambda^\gamma.
\end{equation}
I want to show that for any $c > 0$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x+c) - f(x) =\infty
\end{equation}
My thought: since regular variation is a generalization of power functions, the conclusion is obvious if we think of $f(x) = x^\gamma$. Also, if we assume $f$ is absolutely continuous, then $f'$ is a well-defined regularly varying function with index $\gamma-1 > 0$ (by Karamata's Theorem) , then
$$f(x+c) - f(x) = f'(\hat x) \cdot c,$$
which goes to $\infty$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$.
I tried to show this by just using the definition of regular variation but could not find a clue. Can anyone give a hint or indicate where this result can be found? Thank you!
